# Write into different project's datastore and GBQ using GAE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

We are having two projects **PROJECT-1** and **PROJECT-2** in GCP.

So what we are trying is to run GAE(standard in Python) in **PROJECT-1** will generate some data which should be inserted in `DATASTORE` & `GBQ` in **PROJECT-2**

Have tried to find any documentation for the same but no luck so far so first, is it possible to write into the different project where GAE is running and if yes how and if there is documentation suggesting same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the Cloud Datastore ndb or db libraries to write from GAE standard in python to Cloud Datastore database in another project.